# sqlite3 c++ insert, not inserting

Tags: c++, sqlite

The database is reporting that it opens successfully. When I run it, nothing is being inserted into my table. I tried to pay close attention to single quotes, as a lot of other posts had issues with that, but I still am not seeing any insertions.

```
std::string id_check = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM known_wheels WHERE diameter = '"+ std::to_string(diameter) +"' AND height = '"+ std::to_string(height) +"');";

std::string id_insert = "INSERT INTO known_wheels VALUES ('"+ std::to_string(diameter) +"', '"+ std::to_string(height) +"');";

if(sqlite3_exec(db, id_check.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError) != SQLITE_ROW)
{   
   sqlite3_exec(db, id_insert.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &messageError);
}
else
{
 ROS_INFO("Wheels exists");
}
```

Where I open the db (I acknowledge the fprintf is ancient, it was from the tutorial I was learning with).

```
int wheels_compare::opendb(int argc, char** argv)
{
    sqlite3* db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("wheels.db", &db);

    if(rc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM known_wheels....
```

is not a valid SQL statement, because `IF` can't be used in a SQLite query.
What you want to achieve here is to insert values for `diameter` and `height` that do not already exist, right?
The simplest way to get this functionality is to [create a unique index](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) for the combination of these columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX un_known_wheels ON known_wheels(diameter, height);
```

so you don't have to check before every insert whether the values exist.
 
Or just drop `IF` and keep this:

```
std::string id_check = "SELECT 1 FROM known_wheels WHERE diameter = '"+ std::to_string(diameter) +"' AND height = '"+ std::to_string(height) +"';"
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I will definitely think your unique index idea. So the INSERT function loop is being entered into, nothing is inserting though.

Comment: The result of if(sqlite3_exec(...)) should be (I'm not an expert in c++) `false` because there is an error in the sql statement.

Comment: You are right, it could wrongly be entering the loop. So maybe both SQL statements are incorrect.

Comment: The `INSERT INTO...` statement is correct, but the code never reaches that line.

Comment: I have a print statement directly after it, and the print statement is executing.

Comment: I thought the problem is that you see the message `"Wheels exists"` whatever values that you use.

Comment: Debug and print the variable `id_insert`. What is the result?

Comment: I was, but I switched the logic to check, then I arrived at the insert issue.

Comment: If you always see the message "Wheels exists" this means that the if(sqlite3_exec(..)) condition always returns false, even when the values do not exist in the table. I guess this is the result of the malfomed sql IF NOT EXISTS... statement. Also the INSERT.. statement seems syntactically correct if the concatenated values are correct. But just to be on the safe side print the value of id_insert.

Answer (score 0):

My database was not opening, so therefore none of the SQL commands would work.